# React Native - Scroll to Listview's row via ref not working

Tags: listview, react-native

I have a `ListView` with a `ref` on each `row` and I want to be able to scroll to a specific `row` via its `ref` on press of `TouchableOpacity` like this:

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}
                  onPress={() => this.scrollToRef('item_5')}>
    <Text style={styles.text}>Scroll to row of ref item_5!</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>

<ListView
     ref="listView"
     renderRow={ item => {
               return (
               <View ref={"item_"+item.id} key={"item_"+item.id} style={styles.itemRow}>
                 <Text>ref is {"item_"+item.id}</Text>
                 <Text>{item.text}</Text>
               </View>
               )
               }}
     dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
     enableEmptySections={true}
/>
```

On press of the `TouchableOpacity` no scrolling occurs to row with `ref="item_5"`

Here is a demo:

[image: Scroll to ListView via row ref issue]

[Here is a working fiddle.](https://rnplay.org/apps/HHnFPQ)

How can I get it to scroll to the row with `ref="item_5"` on `TouchableOpacity` press?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is caused due to the row being rendered out of scope of the this.refs (due to the renderRow function).

I was able to handle this by adding a row ref object to store these values:

```js
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.rows = [];
    this.state = {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(numbersDataSource)
    };
  }
```

Next you want to use a reference function instead of a basic text reference to store the row ref value:

```js
<View ref={(row) => this.rows[item.id] = row} key={"item_"+item.id} style={styles.itemRow}>
```

Finally, reference the array object based on it's id value:

```js
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}
                            onPress={() => this.scrollToRef('5')}>
```

```js
scrollToRef(itemRef) {
    this.rows[itemRef].measure((ox, oy, width, height, px, py) => {
```

Additionally, clear the row reference objects each time you update data using componentWillUpdate to keep it nice and tidy.

Comment: I've been stuck on this one for so long! Thank you so much @Momentus Mitch!